# Uber api number of nearby drivers

Tags: driver, uber-api

I was wondering if the current api can tell the number of drivers near a given location. It would be more interesting if i can see how close they are to location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We currently don't expose this granularity of data through the [Rides API](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/getting-started). The closest to this feature would be the estimates related to Uber products. For instance, you can [get the ETA (in seconds) for available Uber products](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/api/v1-estimates-time), which is an indicator of how close driver partners are to the given location.

Thanks for raising the question and expressing your interest in such a feature. It helps us to understand what the community is looking for so we can prioritize what gets built and released in the future!

Keep an eye on the [Uber Developers blog for news around current and upcoming APIs](https://medium.com/uber-developers).

Comment: I would really find this feature useful. Do you know if there are plans to add it?

Comment: This feature is available with the Lyft API and would be a great addition to an Uber API